# How can I package assets (CSS, JS, Images) into a private gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems

I bought a theme from one of those theme websites and they are now integrated properly into my Rails 4 application.

I'd like to package all of these files into a simple **private** gem. I can't follow the tutorials I find online because they only teach you how to create public gems and I don't have the license to redistribute these assets.

How can I create a private gem hosted on something like Github and package my assets into it? They're only js, css and .jpeg|jpg|png files.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials you find online will most likely still function for your needs.

For example, this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem?view=asciicast) walks you through the steps to create a gem and publish it to Github.

Since you need it to be a private gem, just make the repository private on Github so no one else has access to it.